# Special relativity, calculate velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, spacetime, reference-frames

Lets assume that a spaceship travels to a star 8 light-years away, in a time its crew considers to be 8 years. How do we calculate the speed of the ship? Is at as simple as saying: since the star is 8 light-years away and it takes 8 years, they should travel at $v=c$? Or is there any other way to do this?

Comment: "...they should travel at v=c?" No, if they were able to travel at near v=c then the trip would take about 8 years according to their friends on Earth but to the crew it would seem that the trip took no time at all and they arrived at the star instantly. Try sketching out the problem and also write down the equation for time dilation and think it over.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that they go with the speed $v$ wrt their earthy friends. So for them (now onwards 'they' refere to spaceship crew unless otherwise mentioned) the initial distance is $l_0 \sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$ and the planet is coming towards them at the speed of $v$
. Where $l_0$ is 8 light years. Now in their frame the planet takes 8 years to reach them.

Therefore, 8 = 8$(c/v)\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$
So, $v$ = $c/\sqrt2$.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is right, and @Dvij did some nice reasoning.

Just to explain it, which is easy math (but can be confusing because of the two 8's , which will confuse most people, though one is time and the other distance. They could have been unequal numbers), his equation with the two 8's is conceptually:

8 years = time in their frame = distance/v in their frame

Or 8 y = 8 ly/c = distance/v in their frame

This is 8 = c x $l_0 \sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$/v  where we have used Dvij's equation for the Lorentz contracted distance, which is of course right.

That leads to this last equation, and if we set $l_0 = 8$ ly, we get

$\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$ x c/v = 1

And then easily v = c/$\sqrt{2}$

That is his answer and it is correct, conceptually and mathematically. He did some mental unit translations between years and ly.